# Set ASP.Net version using WiX

Tags: asp.net, installation, wix

I am creating an installer for an ASP.Net website using WiX.  How do you set the ASP.Net version in IIS using WiX?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We use this:

First determine the .Net framework root directory from the registry:

```
<Property Id="FRAMEWORKROOT">
  <RegistrySearch Id="FrameworkRootDir" Root="HKLM"
                Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework" 
                Type="directory" Name="InstallRoot" />
</Property>
```

Then, inside the component that installs your website in IIS:

```
<!-- Create and configure the virtual directory and application. -->
<Component Id='WebVirtualDirComponent' Guid='{GUID}' Permanent='no'>
  <iis:WebVirtualDir Id='WebVirtualDir' Alias='YourAlias' Directory='InstallDir' WebSite='DefaultWebSite'  DirProperties='DirProperties'>
    <iis:WebApplication Id='WebApplication' Name='YourAppName' WebAppPool='AppPool'>
      <!-- Required to run the application under the .net 2.0 framework -->
      <iis:WebApplicationExtension Extension="config" CheckPath="yes" Script="yes"
                    Executable="[FRAMEWORKROOT]v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST" />
      <iis:WebApplicationExtension Extension="resx" CheckPath="yes" Script="yes"
                    Executable="[FRAMEWORKROOT]v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST" />
      <iis:WebApplicationExtension Extension="svc" CheckPath="no" Script="yes"
                    Executable="[FRAMEWORKROOT]v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST" />
    </iis:WebApplication>
  </iis:WebVirtualDir>
</Component>
```

For an x64 installer (**THIS IS IMPORTANT**)
Add Win64='yes' to the registry search, because the 32 bits environment on a 64 bits machine has a different registry hive (and a different frameworkroot)

```
<RegistrySearch Id="FrameworkRootDir" Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework" 
        Type="directory" 
        Name="InstallRoot" Win64='yes' />
```

Comment: @thjis: Why are you only registering those three extensions? Should you also register, for instance, aspx and asmx extensions? Should you go ahead a register all extensions listed in IIS just to be sure?

Comment: @ian: We only needed those, you can register all extensions you need.

Comment: Ah, WiX: where the correct answer is 15 lines of cryptic XML, which counts as "supereasy" and is still an incomplete answer (only some extensions are handled, and not even the most common one of .aspx) that doesn't cover all cases (not 64 bit).

Comment: @Anthony the cool thing about Stackoverflow.com is that you may edit questions if you have enough rep, or provide a better answer. That way everybody wins..

Comment: Sadly, as far as I can tell, there is no really good answer to this in WiX.

Answer (score 13):

Here is what worked for me after wrestling with it:

```
  <Property Id="FRAMEWORKBASEPATH">
     <RegistrySearch Id="FindFrameworkDir" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework" Name="InstallRoot" Type="raw"/>
  </Property>
  <Property Id="ASPNETREGIIS" >
     <DirectorySearch Path="[FRAMEWORKBASEPATH]" Depth="4" Id="FindAspNetRegIis">
        <FileSearch Name="aspnet_regiis.exe" MinVersion="2.0.5"/>
     </DirectorySearch>
  </Property>

  <CustomAction Id="MakeWepApp20" Directory="TARGETDIR" ExeCommand="[ASPNETREGIIS] -norestart -s W3SVC/[WEBSITEID]/ROOT/[VIRTUALDIR]" Return="check"/>

  <InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action="MakeWepApp20" After="InstallFinalize">ASPNETREGIIS AND NOT Installed</Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

[WEBSITEID] and [VIRTUALDIR] are properties you have to define yourself.  [VIRTUALDIR] is only necessary if you are setting the ASP.NET version for an application rather than an entire website.

The sequencing of the custom action is critical.  Executing it before InstallFinalize will cause it to fail because the web application isn't available until after that.

Thanks to Chris Burrows for a proper example of finding the aspnet_regiis executable (Google "Using WIX to Secure a Connection String").

jb

Comment: Thanks mate, in my opinion this is the most consistent answer here. I tried the other suggestion (which leaves the app pool as .NET 1.1) and it was just over-complicated and didn't work on my MVC app.

One point, I had to use the LongName attribute for FileSearch (instead of Name which it complained only supports 8.3 format).

Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, what would the ExeCommand be for setting it for the entire website?

Comment: Also, would [WEBSITEID] correspond to <iis:WebSite Id="WEBSITEID">?

Comment: Note that this will result in a separate application pool being created for ASP.NET 4, meaning that your app may not be running where you thought it was. We had to drop this approach because of this problem.

Comment: @David Hodgson (only 1 year late, but might help someone!), WEBSITEID corresponds to the element `<iis:WebSite SiteID="">`.

Comment: How are you determining the WEBSITEID?  Are you passing it in as a PROPERTY, or is there a search capability that supplies the property for you?

Comment: I think this is the best answer, supporting older IIS versions and only making any necessary changes using the standard MS supported tools. I also added the UI\ProgressText from other answers here, and in case IIS 7 or later is installed I think specifying the managed pipeline type and version should also be done.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to enable ASP 2.0 on the server

```
<iis:WebServiceExtension Id="ExtensionASP2" Group="ASP.NET v2.0.50727" Allow="yes" File="[NETFRAMEWORK20INSTALLROOTDIR]aspnet_isapi.dll" Description="ASP.NET v2.0.50727"/>
```

[Here is the sof-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269991/set-existing-web-service-extension-to-allow-using-wix)

Comment: where do you reference that Id afterwards?

Comment: Nowhere, the hole „iis:WebServiceExtension”-tag is inside a component-tag. That’s how it is referenced. The Id isn’t actually used anywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is basically the same as others seen here; I just wanted to offer people another example.

Given the number of file extensions that ASP.NET handles, and that the list changes in each version, I think the most reliable solution is to run `aspnet_regiis` at the end of the installation. This does mean though, that I don't have any support for rollback or uninstallation. I you're creating a new application in IIS, it doesn't really matter because it will be deleted by Wix. If you're modifying an existing application, perhaps you could find out from the registry what version of ASP.NET is configured, and run that version's `aspnet_regiis` to undo your changes.

The following uses Wix 3.5.

```
<Fragment>
    <!-- Use the properties in Wix instead of doing your own registry search. -->
    <PropertyRef Id="IISMAJORVERSION"/>
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR"/>

    <!-- The code I'm using is intended for IIS6 and above, and it needs .NET 4 to be
    installed. -->
    <Condition Message="This application requires the .NET Framework 4.0. Please install the required version of the .NET Framework, then run this installer again.">
        <![CDATA[Installed OR (NETFRAMEWORK40FULL)]]>
    </Condition>
    <Condition Message="This application requires Windows Server 2003 and Internet Information Services 6.0 or better.">
        <![CDATA[Installed OR (VersionNT >= 502)]]>
    </Condition>

    <!-- Populates the command line for CAQuietExec. IISWEBSITEID and IISVDIRNAME 
    could be set to default values, passed in by the user, or set in your installer's 
    UI. -->
    <CustomAction Id="ConfigureIis60AspNetCommand" Property="ConfigureIis60AspNet"
                  Execute="immediate"
                  Value="&quot;[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]aspnet_regiis.exe&quot; -norestart -s &quot;W3SVC/[IISWEBSITEID]/ROOT/[IISVDIRNAME]&quot;" />
    <CustomAction Id="ConfigureIis60AspNet" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" 
                  Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="ConfigureIis60AspNetCommand" After="CostFinalize"/>

        <!-- Runs the aspnet_regiis command immediately after Wix configures IIS. 
        The condition shown here assumes you have a selectable feature in your 
        installer with the ID "WebAppFeature" that contains your web components. The 
        command will not be run if that feature is not being installed, or if IIS is 
        not version 6. It *will* run if the application is being repaired. 

        SKIPCONFIGUREIIS is a property defined by Wix that causes it to skip the IIS
        configuration. -->
        <Custom Action="ConfigureIis60AspNet" After="ConfigureIIs" Overridable="yes">
            <![CDATA[((&WebAppFeature = 3) OR (REINSTALL AND (!WebAppFeature = 3))) 
            AND (NOT SKIPCONFIGUREIIS) AND (IISMAJORVERSION = "#6")]]>
        </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
    <UI>
        <ProgressText Action="ConfigureIis60AspNetCommand"
            >Configuring ASP.NET</ProgressText>
        <ProgressText Action="ConfigureIis60AspNet"
            >Configuring ASP.NET</ProgressText>
    </UI>

</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a different way by using the WiX WebApplicationExtension. You can check out the full solution [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg11420.html) and [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg11451.html).

I like Wix so far, but man does it takes a lot of digging to find what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried this approach with my MVC app and it just wouldn't play nicely at all. Using aspnet_regiis within a CustomAction to change the AppPool to .NET 2.0 worked for me (see John Burns answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit simpler. I don’t know if this works on updating an existing AppPool, but works for creating an APP Pool and setting the .NET version.

```
<iis:WebServiceExtension Id="AMS_AppPool" Name="AccountManagementSVC1" Identity="other"  ManagedPipelineMode="integrated" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" User="AMS_AppPoolUser" RecycleMinutes="120" />
```

Comment: Try that on Windows Server 2003 to set .NET 4, you will find ASP.NET is left at version 2.0. It is necessary to set the configuration of the virtual directory to the higher version when the default web site or server settings are lower. Maybe that is a bug in WIX, that it doesn't remap the application pool .NET version setting (which only exists on newer IIS versions) to the virtual directory setting on older versions.

Comment: Checking the documentation shows that setting only supports IIS 7 or higher. Second best choice for me is running the aspnet_regiis as a custom action for older versions (see other answers here). So you can only use that if you are sure all your customers/users have Windows 2008/Vista or higher.

Answer (score 0):

- First find the correct .NET version folder. Use DirectorySearch/FileSearch to perform search.
- Use the above path to call aspnet_regiis.exe and set the version for the webapp from a custom action.

  `aspnet_regiis.exe -s W3SVC/1/ROOT/SampleApp1`

Comment: The "1" in that path is problematic. It is a site identifier. If you have more than one web site on the IIS installation, then the site that you want may have a different number, and if so then this command won't affect it, but will alter an unrelated site instead. More details at More details at http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/05/30/ASPNet_5F00_regiis.exe-tool_2C00_-setting-the-default-version-without-forcing-an-upgrade-on-all-sites.aspx