# Wildcard application maps in IIS using WIX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, wix

Is it possible to add a wildcard application map in IIS6 from the wix installer package? I know how to add [application extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163531/set-aspnet-version-using-wix) however can't see any way to add wildcards.

This is needed for ASP.Net MVC to function properly.

Answer (score 11):

Found the answer.  You use the **WebApplicationExtension** (found in WixIisExtension), without specifying an Extension attribute.  Here's the wildcard mapping for ASP.NET 2.0:

```
<iis:WebApplicationExtension CheckPath="no"
         Script="yes"
         Executable="[FRAMEWORKROOT]v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll"
         Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST"/>
```