# iis wildcard redirect - wix issue

Tags: iis, wix, wildcard

```
<Component Id="WebVirtualDirComponentX86" Guid="E6995A18-BC79-4A72-BD82-F3961D72EC00">
<WebVirtualDir Id="WebVirtualDirX86" Alias="TestWebApp" Directory="INSTALLDIR" WebSite="OurWebSite">
    <WebApplication Id="WebApplicationX86" Name="TestWebApp" >
<WebApplicationExtension CheckPath="no"   Script="yes"   Executable="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
                        Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST"/>
</WebApplication>
</WebVirtualDir>

 <WebSite Id="OurWebSite" Description="our Web Site">
      <WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="3333" />
</WebSite>
```

when i add wildcard mapping for iis using wix, it works fine.
but ASP.NET version on the ASP.NET tab of iis settings is blank.

this is happening only on windows server 2003 server.
could some one suggest me a idea to overcome this problem.
or tell me how to select asp.net 2.0 version for the website/virtualdirectory/webapp

Answer (score 1):

To fix this on your machine, you need to run this from the command line:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis /s W3SVC/1/ROOT/<YourVirtualDirectoryName>
```

Replace "<YourVirtualDirectoryName>" with the Alias your site runs under.

This is assuming that you have only one website configured in IIS. If you have more, replace the "1" after "W3SVC/" with the website id number.

To fix it from within wix you may need to use the IIS etensions as demonstrated here: [Set ASP.Net version using WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163531/set-asp-net-version-using-wix) and here:
[Wildcard application maps in IIS using WIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268146/wildcard-application-maps-in-iis-using-wix).